# org.hibernate.type.SerializationException: could not deserialize error, using CriteriaBuilder API to read json field from postgreSQL

Tags: postgresql, hibernate, serialization, persistence, criteria-api

In my postgreSQL table I have a column named details of type json. While reading it from the database using criteriabuilder api I am getting serialization error.

Field in the model class mapped to the postgreSQL database

Detail.java contains the below field

```
@Column(name = "details")
PGobject details;
```

DetailDTO.java contains the below field

```
@JsonProperty("app_details")
PGobject appDetails;
```

```
CriteriaBuilder criteriaBuilder = entityManager.getCriteriaBuilder();
CriteriaQuery<DetailDTO> criteriaQuery = criteriaBuilder.createQuery(DetailDTO.class);
Root<Detail> root = criteriaQuery.from(Detail.class);
criteriaQuery.select(root.get("details"));

List<DetailDTO> detailDTOS = entityManager.createQuery(criteriaQuery).getResultList();
```

Below error occurs during the execution of the getResultList() function

```
javax.persistence.PersistenceException: org.hibernate.type.SerializationException: could not deserialize
```

Comment: can you add the whole code of DetailDTO?

Comment: for `Detail.class` is working? maybe is better to keep the `appDetails` attribute same as in the `Detail.class`, `details`, and keep the  `@JsonProperty("app_details")` to send the json with desired name